# Jmeter 5.4.1: Distributed mode : "Connection refused to host: nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect"

Tags: jmeter, connection, rmi

I am setting up distributed test with jmeter 5.4.1 in two windows VMs.
Started the jmeter server in slave machine. with below change in jmeter.properties file(both master and slave)

> server.rmi.ssl.disable=true

Added slave machine ip in master and running the test from GUI mode. getting connection refused error:

> ERROR o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Failed to create engine at
> 192.168.xxx.xx java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.xxx.xx; nested exception is:    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect    at
> sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:623)
> ~[?:?]    at
> sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:209)
> ~[?:?]    at
> sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:196)
> ~[?:?]    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:343)
> ~[?:?]    at
> sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(RegistryImpl_Stub.java:116)
> ~[?:?]    at
> org.apache.jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine.getEngine(ClientJMeterEngine.java:71)
> ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]    at
> org.apache.jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine.(ClientJMeterEngine.java:84)
> ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]    at
> org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.createEngine(DistributedRunner.java:243)
> ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]    at
> org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.getClientEngine(DistributedRunner.java:220)
> ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]    at
> org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.init(DistributedRunner.java:92)
> ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]    at
> org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.RemoteStart.doAction(RemoteStart.java:79)
> ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]    at
> org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:87)
> ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]    at
> org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:69)
> ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]    at
> java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316)
> ~[?:?]    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
> ~[?:?]    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721) ~[?:?]    at
> java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715) ~[?:?]     at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
> [?:?]     at
> java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
> [?:?]     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740) [?:?]
> at
> java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
> [?:?]     at
> java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
> [?:?]     at
> java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
> [?:?]     at
> java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
> [?:?]     at
> java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> [?:?]     at
> java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90) [?:?]
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
> at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[?:?]    at
> sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:576) ~[?:?]   at
> sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:565) ~[?:?]   at
> sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588) ~[?:?]   at
> java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:333) ~[?:?]     at
> java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:645) ~[?:?]   at
> java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:595) ~[?:?]   at
> java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:519) ~[?:?]    at
> java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:293) ~[?:?]    at
> sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(TCPDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
> ~[?:?]    at
> sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:617)
> ~[?:?]

Comment: Any updates regarding the issue? please share how you solved it if you did.

Comment: We had to get new VMs created for this and then it started working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your "architecture" of one master and one slave doesn't have any sense as you have only one load generator, if there are no plans to scale it further - you can just [run your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) and that would be it.

However if going forward you want to add more slaves, make sure that

1. The machines are in the same [subnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) and can reach one another (or alternatively the appropriate routing is set up)
2. The following ports are [open in Windows Firewall](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-open-port-windows-firewall) :

   - Port `1099` (or whatever is the SERVER_PORT)
   - The port you define as `server.rmi.localport`
   - The port(s) you define as  `client.rmi.localport`
3. You started the slave via `jmeter-server.bat` command

More information:

- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)

Comment: This is just for POC, will plan to scale the number of slaves further. I tried all this but somehow it did not work however it should have worked. I will check with the links you have provide if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure master and slaves use the same rmi keystore file (rmi_keystore.jks). I created it on the master and scp it to the slaves.